# python pandas - data frame - indexing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame(df1) like the below:

```
    A   B   C   D
0  a0  b0  c0  d0
1  a1  b1  c1  d1
2  a2  b2  c2  d2
3  a3  b3  c3  d3
```

I did the drop operation:

```
df1.drop([0],inplace=True)
```

so the data frame like this:

```
    A   B   C   D
1  a1  b1  c1  d1
2  a2  b2  c2  d2
3  a3  b3  c3  d3
```

after that when I check

```
df.iloc[[0]]
```

This is the result:

```
    A   B   C   D
1  a1  b1  c1  d1
```

I am confused, I am expecting a Null Data frame, why is it showing index `1` output?

Comment: df.iloc[[0]] is query the position , you  are looking for .loc

Comment: `df1.drop([0],inplace=True)` removes the 0th row. See documentation: [http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop][1]

Therefore when you make a row call like `df.iloc[[0]]`
The result is

        A   B   C   D
    1  a1  b1  c1  d1

  [1]: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html?highlight=drop